# Django Query: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    metric = models.IntegerField(choices=....)
    date = models.DateField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    linkedObject = models.ForeignKey()
    .....
```

What I would like to achieve is to create the sum of all values for the newest metric and date.

What I already use is order_by + distinct to get the newest value for each metric choice. This works.

```
Data.objects.all().order_by("metric", "-date").distinct("metric")
```

I tried to combine this with aggregate to make the next step:

```
Data.objects.all().order_by("metric", "-date").distinct("metric").annotate(Sum("value"))
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.
```

Hint: I use postgres as database

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with:

```py
Data.objects.order_by("metric", "-date").values(
    "metric", "date",
).annotate(value_sum=Sum("value"))
```

This will group the sum by `metric` and `date` and return the result with the desired sorting.